# How can itereate through checkboxes using forlopp in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to check whether the checkbox values are ticked or not using 'for' loop.

```
CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk + i];
```

from searches i got this line. what this tab_patients denote ?`

```
 string chk = "CheckBox";
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++)
        { 
           // CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)tab_patients.Controls[chk + i];
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.Page.Form.FindControl("chk"+i.ToString());

            if(cb.Checked==true)

            {
                check = i + "0" + k;
               }

        }}
```

Comment: where you have this check box?

Comment: Why didn't you use a checkboxlist?

Comment: CHECKBOXES CREATED IN .aspx page

Comment: I have 32 checkboxes. created statically . see my code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and create the checkboxes with checkboxlists: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="SomeElement" runat="server" 
                                   AutoPostBack="true"
                                   RepeatColumns="4"
                                   EnableViewState="true">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

With the Repeatcolumns property you are telling the element, that you infact want 4 columns, so the control will devide your 32 elements by 4 and group those checkboxes by the pack of 8.

After this, you can iterate through every list like this:

```
foreach(var cb in checkboxlistID) 
{
  if(cb.Checked)
  {
     //do something
  }
}
```

On top of that, here is some old code showing you how to fill a checkboxlist with data fetched from a SQL-query. You can ignore the if expression, which is checking if there is cached data, from which to fill all the checkboxes.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string Query = @"SELECT * from level";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(Query, connection);
            if (Session["SavedLevelItems"] != null)
                {
                    CheckBoxListLevel.Items.Clear();
                    List<ListItem> SessionList = (List<ListItem>)Session["SavedLevelItems"];
                    foreach (var item in SessionList)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            CheckBoxListLevel.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                        catch { }

                    }
                }
            else
            {
                connection.Open();
                CheckBoxListLevel.DataTextField = "bez_level";
                CheckBoxListLevel.DataValueField = "id_level";
                OleDbDataReader ListReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                CheckBoxListLevel.DataSource = ListReader;
                CheckBoxListLevel.DataBind();
                ListReader.Close(); ListReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But how can i arrange this check box list. ?? i have 32 checkboxes.where in each row of a table only 4 of them should be have.. ie in a 4*8 manner..so that why i dont use checkboxlists here